# EF CTP4 : "The context cannot be used while the model is being created."

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ctp4

I have two entities : Student and Class.

they have a many-to-many relationship between each other :

```
class Student
{
   ICollection<Class> Classes{get;set;}
}

class Class
{
   ICollection<Student> Students{get;set;}
}
```

when I try to execute the following statement :

```
return _db.Students.Where(s => s.Email == email).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get this error message :

```
 "The context cannot be used while the model is being created."
```

Comment: Do you know that CTP4 is obsolete version? There was already CTP5 with several changes and now you can download EF 4.1 RC: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2dc5ddac-5a96-48b2-878d-b9f49d87569a

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue/exception when I forgot to put connection string from the app.config in project where codefirst model was to web.config in webui project from where I was running my app and referenced CF.
Maybe not your case, but worth checking.